# string(49) "select * from php mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of making a web page that's meant to display data that's within a database. The database is stored in `MySQL` and I'm making the web page in `PHP`. The `PHP` code that I have is

```
<form action="list_projects.php" method="post">
    <p>Choose Search Type: <br /></p>
    <select name="searchtype">
        <option value="partNo">Part Number</option>
        <option value="pname">Part Name</option>
        <option value="color">Part Colour</option>
        <option value="weight">Part Weight</option>
        <option value="city">City</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <p>Enter Search Term: </p>
    <br />
    <input name="searchterm" type="text" size="20"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>

<?php
    $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
    $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
    if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
        echo 'No search details. Go back and try again.';
        exit;
    }

    $query = "select * from project where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
    var_dump($query);

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
    for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Part Number: ";
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['partNo']));
        echo "</strong><br />Part Name: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['pname']);
        echo "<br />Part Colour: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['color']);
        echo "<br />Part Weight: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['weight']);
        echo "<br />City";
        echo stripcslashes($row['city']);
        echo "</p>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

but when I run it, I get `string(49) "select * from project where projectNo like '%J1%'" Number of projects found:` This `PHP` script is meant to load different projects that's within the database and in a `welcome.php` script that calls this script connects to the database and it does connect to it correctly.

Comment: If you run the query `select * from project where projectNo like '%J1%'` directly, do you get any results?

Comment: Remove the `var_dump($query);`, that is getting concatenated onto `echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";` Does it run then

Comment: @RiggsFolly It has got rid of the error, but it won't display anything from the database

Comment: It is also a very good idea to run [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on the `$_POST` values as well before they are plugged into the SQL query. Otherwise any search term featuring a `'` or certain other characters can screw up your database.

Comment: you have a typo on `stripcslashes($row['city']);`

Comment: [turn on error logging on your PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: @Martin Thanks, I've sorted that one out. However, I'm still not getting any data being displayed from the database

Comment: please also review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's painful, I want to rewrite your code and show you how you *should* be doing this:

Please note that at the top of your page is a reference to an include file in which you would set your database variable (`$link`).

```
<?php
//include "../../reference/to/mysql/login.php";
/***
 * The below code block should be in your include file referenced above 
 ***/
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
/***
 * End connection block
 ***/

/***
 * Your data is POSTed so it can not be trusted and must at the
 * very least be escaped using the below functions.
 ***/
$searchtype=mysqli_real_escape_String($link,$_POST['searchtype']);
$searchterm=mysqli_real_escape_String($link,$_POST['searchterm']);
$searchterm=trim($searchterm);
/***
 * Because your $searchtype is a column reference you need to ensure
 * it fits the allowed characters criteria for MySQL columns
 ***/
$searchtype = preg_replace("/[a-z0-9_]/i","",$searchtype);
```

Please read the [MySQL manual about the allowed characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) to use in column names. `$` is also allowed but I'm removing that from here because you really should not be using that symbol as a column name character.

```
if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
    echo 'No search details. Go back and try again.';
    exit;
}

$query = "select * FROM project WHERE ".$searchtype." LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query)  or die("Line ".__LINE__." Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i++;
    echo "<p><strong>".$i.". Part Number: ";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['partNo']);
    echo "</strong><br />Part Name: ";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['pname']);
    echo "<br />Part Colour: ";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['color']);
    echo "<br />Part Weight: ";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['weight']);
    echo "<br />City ";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['city']);
    echo "</p>";
}
?>
```

Hopefully you can see here that I have replaced your `for` loop with a `while` loop that does the same thing, taking each row from the database one at a time and outputting it as an array with identifier `$row` .

I have also used `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of your fetch_assoc.

I have corrected the spelling mistake in your `stripslashes` function, but also replaced stripslashes with `htmlspecialchars` because stripslashes is an old and almost useless renegade function that should not be used with even remotely modern Database interfacing

Your issue is also that this page coded here has not had `$link` declared for it, the $link idenitifier ***needs to be set at the top of every page that wants to connect to the database***. You need to remember that PHP does not remember standard variables across pages so just because you setup `$link` in `welcome.php` does NOT mean that it is known in this page here.

- Use `or die (mysqli_error($link));` appended to the end of your queries to feedback to you what errors occur.
- You *must* also get into the habit of using [PHP Error Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to make any headway in solving your own issues.
- `$link` is usually set up in a [PHP include file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) that you simply call at the top of every PHP page that requires it.
- IF needed, [details about how to connect to MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226019/php-mysqli-connect-function).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've var dumped the wrong variable. You could try this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE ".$searchtype." LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die("Line ".__LINE__." Error found: ".mysqli_error($link)); // If there's an error, it should show here.
```

Comment: I made a minor edit to further illustrate the error details upon output, showing which line the error appears on.

Comment: Yes, it's a lot more accurate if we pinpoint the line no. Nice one! :)

Comment: It's showing it's on line 28. The line that is `$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die("Line ".__LINE__." Error found: ".mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: please think before you type; we've just told you to put the error and you've shown us the line we told you to write so you don't need to repeat it back to us! please tell us what the error statement actually says!!! @smitthy . Edit your question and insert the error message at the bottom. Cheers

Comment: @Martin I've copied that line into my code, but it's only saying the line number and not giving any kind of error, it's only saying `Line 28 Error found: `

Comment: ok @smitthy have you set up $link ? Is it a valid MySQL connection link?

Comment: @Martin It is set up in the `Welcome.php` file, the `Welcome.php` file tests the connection and says if I'm connected to the server or not then I click on the 'projects' tab and it'll take me to the `list_projects.php` file as shown in the question, which is meant to show different pieces of data from a database

Comment: @smitthy I think that is your issue, `$link` is undefined, please read my answer